# Take SharePoint backup using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is any Graph API available to take backup of SharePoint online list and library.
If no then is any another way excluding PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

(1) Check Power automate or [Microsoft Flow/connectors](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-microsoft-flow-to-extract-sharepoint-online-list-data/) to see if it fits your scenario/requirement. But always keep an eye on throttling incase if you're going to handle good number of items.
(2) In addition, you may want to get it started from [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-backup-strategies-for-a-cloudy-day/m-p/225418), as it talks about all the possible options for entire SharePoint.